# Can not read context value in another component using react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext)

export default function AuthProvider({ children }) {

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)
    
    setInterval( () => setNumber(number+1), 10000 )

    const valueToBeShared = {number}


     return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={ valueToBeShared }>
            {children}

        </AuthContext.Provider>
     );
};
```

**FooterComponent.jsx**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

function FooterComponent() {
     const authContext = useContext(AuthContext)

      console.log(`Footer component - ${authContext.number}`);

      return (
         <div>
           Your Footer
         </div>
     )
   }

   export default FooterComponent
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'number')
> at FooterComponent (:64:49)
> at renderWithHooks (:12163:28)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (:15575:23)
> at beginWork (:16592:24)
> at beginWork$1 (:20001:24)
> at performUnitOfWork (:19458:22)
> at workLoopSync (:19392:15)
> at renderRootSync (:19370:17)
> at recoverFromConcurrentError (:18968:30)

**Unable to read number in FooterComponent**

**1. Added React.createContext();**

**2. Checked createContext(number);**

Comment: Kindly review your question, you are missing `AuthContext.js` code. Make an edit of it.

Comment: @Kabileesh G updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have enclosed the **Components** in the `App` with the `AuthProvider` to make use of the Provider functions and values.

```
import AuthProvider from "./path to AuthProvider"

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
          // Your routes or any other components that needs to use the Provider
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure FooterComponent is under a wrapped element of the provider. Second, as you name your file AuthContext.js you need to import it as it

```
import {} from './AuthContext.js'
```

You can name your file as index.js under an AuthContext folder and then you can import it like this:

```
import {..} from './AuthContext'
```